# Arreylist<Object> show as per section in viewpager list

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, filter

I have an `ArrayList<Model> mList`

and a Model class that looks like

```
public class Model{
    String value;
    String name;
    String dob;   

    //getters & setters
 }
```

I have view pager which has 5 fragments.  mList holds the full list, ie value = All. which I am showing in the 1st fragment. I want to filter/sort for the other fragments. For instance, 2nd should have only value = k ,for 3rd value = B... what is the best way to get a sorted list and pass list.. for now I am doing

```
ArrayList<Model> newlist = new ArrayList<Model>();

for{int i =0 ;i> mlist.size();i++}{
    if(mList.getvalue.equal("k")){
        newList.add(mList(i))                                   
    }      
}
```

and passing newlist to listview 
but now how can I update the value in mList when the user clicks on one row because that row will have the value newList position...

Basically I have some condition for mList say user have to click one item for k,b etc that I want to check.

1) What is a good way to get sorted/filter list in different fragments?

2) How can I update the newlist value of the item clicked in mList?